# What type of behaviour is this?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang

**This question is looking for a standardese quote explicitly explaining why this behavior is wrong.**

The code below including `<stdio.h>` inside `main` ,

```
int main()
{
 #include <stdio.h>
 printf("hello , world \n");
 return 0;
}
```

On `gcc -Wall in.c -o in.out` It successfully compiles and prints `hello , world`.

But on `clang in.c -o in.out` It gives me this error :

```
/usr/include/stdio.h:353:12: error: implicit declaration of 'fprintf' requires 

inclusion of the header <stdio.h>
extern int fprintf (FILE *__restrict __stream,
           ^
1 error generated.
```

My doubt is what kind of behaviour is this ? Is this undefined behaviour or what ?

Also I am not able to find the documentation related to it.

EDIT : The problem is that I found this code somewhere similar to it but I can't post that code exactly so I posted this kind of Demo code.I know the Placing `stdio.h` outside the main.

Comment: You know that something like this is easy to check nowadays - http://ideone.com/z2m2yJ. Of course, it will not compile on GCC.

Comment: @It's `gcc 4.3` on IDEONE , but on my laptop `gcc 4.5` It's compiling

Comment: This is from gcc 4.5.1 - http://ideone.com/io4JNG.

Comment: @SChepurin : but why on my system it's giving this , any way I got it , It's undefined behaviour.. from melpomene answer

Comment: I guess, we shall leave it as "undefined behavior" of implementation because it compiles in codepad.org -http://codepad.org/I5igOBeN

Comment: The error is not an instance of undefined behaviour.  I'll edit my answer in a moment to explain my interpretation.

Comment: Interestingly, my gcc-4.6.2 accepts it even with `-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` when I compile without optimisation, but throws out a heap of errors when I compile with optimisations but without warnings enabled.

Comment: @Kevin A. Naudé - I mean, the "UB" of compiler being implemented this way.

Comment: My answer arose from the assumption that local function declarations should be treated distinctly from global ones.  Now I see that my own compiler (MSVC) simply promotes the local function declarations to global ones, as in the reported GCC case. Perhaps that is normal -- a possible dark corner of the C standard.  I was not aware of this when answering, so I must withdraw my unreliable answer.

Comment: `gcc 4.6.2 -Wall` does _not_ accept this code. You get various warnings about functions declared as extern. Nor does -std=c99 -pedantic make any difference.

Comment: @Lundin Mine does, without optimisations. Throws a fit with `-O`, but is dead silent without.

Comment: @DanielFischer That's weird, are you sure you are compiling a copy/paste version of the OP's code? What gcc port are you using? I compiled with Mingw.

Comment: @Lundin Yup, copy paste. Even a second copy paste after reading your comment. `gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.6.2` is the version. Maybe it's something the distribution patched. clang version 3.0 (branches/release_30 145598) exhibits like behaviour, the difference is that reports only one error with optimisations.

Answer (score 5):

C99, 7.1.2/4:

> [...] If
>   used, a header shall be included outside of any external declaration or definition, and it
>   shall first be included before the first reference to any of the functions or objects it
>   declares, or to any of the types or macros it defines.

4/2:

> If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears outside of a constraint is violated, the
>   behavior is undefined.

6.9/4:

> As discussed in 5.1.1.1, the unit of program text after preprocessing is a translation unit,
>   which consists of a sequence of external declarations. These are described as ‘‘external’’
>   because they appear outside any function (and hence have file scope).

So I think this is undefined behavior.

Comment: So which condition falls under this?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore "header shall be included outside of any external declaration or definition" but the OP put it inside of definition of main()?

Comment: @ÖöTiib so is the definition of main an external definition or an external declaration? I honestly don't know what either means, I thought `extern int x;` is an external declaration.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore when there is no keyword 'static' on function declaration or definition then it has implicitly external linkage. But that is not what the standard probably means. It just means external in sense of being outside of that include file.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11: 17.6.2.2/3:

> A translation unit shall include a header only outside of any external declaration or definition, and shall
>   include the header lexically before the first reference in that translation unit to any of the entities declared
>   in that header.

`main()` is extern, so is not a proper context for include.

Comment: Note that "external" is doesn't not necessarily mean "extern". For example, a `static` function is still an external declaration. See melpomene's answer. It's confusing terminology to be sure.

Answer (score -2):

Try including the header file outside of the main method. Like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 printf("hello , world \n");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 The question was not "how to fix", it was "is this explicitly forbidden".

Comment: I know that ... already..This is not the answer i am looking for please read question carefully